# MaterialShowcaseView show view over action bar

Tags: android, showcaseview

How to put view over action bar items in the code below?
I am using https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView.

```
 config.setFadeDuration(20);
    // config.setDelay(1);
    config.setMaskColor(act.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_black_overlay));
    MaterialShowcaseSequence sequence = new MaterialShowcaseSequence(act, id);
    sequence.setConfig(config);

        sequence.addSequenceItem(view[i], text[i], "");

    }
    sequence.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This has not been implemented yet but I will add it to the project TODO list.

In the meantime you could possibly hash something together yourself using reflection. The details of this depends on which ActionBar implementation you are using.

The MaterialShowcaseView was heavily inspired by the original [Showcaseview](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) project and they implemented this. See [here](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/targets/ActionBarViewWrapper.java) for some clues on how you might use reflection to find the item in the action bar.

Comment: possible to give snippet for same ?